# How to embed social network comment app into website

Tags: django

I want to make a blog that user login by using there social network account like facebook, g+ or twitter and can leave there comments on my site by there account. How can I do that? I know some project like django-allauth or django-social-auth to login. Yet I dont know how to embed comment app into my page. Do I need create my own comment model? or just use there service? Thanks for your reading

Answer (score 2):

I dont actually need to answer, because `"comments plugin facebook"` in google gives enough information to start with, but you need this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments

first embed the sdk into your base.html

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.4&appId=YOURAPPID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and then there where comments should appear this code:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/" data-numposts="5"></div>
```

the modules like django-allauth provide you with things like login with facebook, not these easy things e.g. comments..